# Criar uma tabela separando datas por trimestre com React e Node

Tags: node.js, react, axios, sequelize-js, material-ui

A tabela precisa ficar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já consegui criar uma tabela usando o Sequelize com os dados de cada unidade, com cnpj e tudo mais, e fiz uma tabela de datas relacionada a essa tabela de unidades. a relação ficou o seguinte:

```
db.unidades = require("./CompreBem/unidades.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.datas = require("./CompreBem/datas.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.unidades.hasMany(db.datas, { as: "datas" });
db.datas.belongsTo(db.unidades);
```

A tabela está em React, no componente da tabela ficou o seguinte:

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="caption table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell className={classes.teste} align="right">  </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Unidade</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Nº CTI</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">CNPJ</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Trim.1</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Trim.2</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Trim.3</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Trim.4</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {Object.keys(unidades).map((unidade, i) => (
              <TableRow className={classes.row} key={i}>
                <TableCell align="right">{unidades[unidade].numero}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{unidades[unidade].unidade}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{unidades[unidade].ntci}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{unidades[unidade].cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3/$4-$5") }</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">1</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">2</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">3</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">4</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
```

Eu fiz um useState para a tabela unidades, fiz a requisição axios e fiz esse tratamento para que apareça na tabela, agora eu preciso que fique as últimas datas de cada trimestre nas suas respectivas unidades. A requisição que eu faço para pegar esses dados fica nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor, estou me quebrando nesse código, não consigo pensar em uma maneira de mostrar esses trimestres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os registros de datas vem ordenadas dentro de cada unidade imagino que possa fazer desta forma:

```
{Object.keys(unidades).map((unidade, i) => (
          <TableRow className={classes.row} key={i}>
            <TableCell align="right">{unidades[unidade].numero}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{unidades[unidade].unidade}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{unidades[unidade].ntci}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{unidades[unidade].cnpj.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3/$4-$5") }</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">unidades[unidade].datas[0]['data']</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">unidades[unidade].datas[1]['data']</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">unidades[unidade].datas[2]['data']</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">unidades[unidade].datas[3]['data']</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
```

Pode colocar um ternario para verificar se tem o indice do array para não dar nenhum erro exibindo uma outra informação.
Toda o agrupamento de datas para as unidades pode ser feita no proprio service no back-end, fazendo com que o front-end so exiba.

Comment: Você é um deus, eu não precisava mais dessa condição de trimestre, mas sua resposta resolveu toda minha vida, muito obrigado, no final era só usar ['data'], eu já estava fazendo map com filter com não sei mais o que. muito obrigado mesmo.